# Rebuild client if non-static data members change of an exported class (DLL)?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

Let's say I have a C++ class which is exported outside its DLL. There are some client dlls/programs using this exported class.

```
#define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport )  

class DllExport MyClass {  
   // ...  

};
```

By exporting the class, all its member functions(even private) and static data members are exported. What about non-static data members? If I add or change some non-static data members, do I have to rebuild all clients that are linking to this dll's import library(.lib)?

I ran into some random crashes and the above is my guess of the cause.

Comment: ABI incompatibilities between different compilers and different versions of the same compilers make exporting classes a tricky proposition, and I would argue, a bad idea. Why do you need to export the entire class, rather than just certain public interface functions?

Comment: ideal vs reality, man. Working on a legacy project with things severer to worry about..

Comment: Then you will have to rebuild everything. Problems like this are why COM was invented. If it was as simple as `__declspec(dllexport)`, Don Box would have been out of a job.

Comment: Good point, Cody..